# Unable to open Office files from a SharePoint 2013 on an iPad

Tags: office-integration

[Unable to open Office files from a SharePoint 2010 on an iPad](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2955397)

As SharePoint uses ActiveX even in 2013, this problem still happens, doesn't it?

OR is there any way to fix this?

Regards,

Comment: Technet says "Office Web Apps full functionality is supported on iPad versions 2 and 3 using iOS 6.0 or later versions. Limited viewing and editing functionality is also supported on iPad versions 1, 2, 3 using iOS version 5.1."

Comment: That's true when we talk about OWA. The above link is talking about SharePoint and Office App for iPad. When open a document in SharePoint 2013 **without** owa, it seems to use ActiveX (OpenDocument, maybe). But in SharePoint Online, the integration with Office App works quite good.